# How to delay execution inside a closure being called by an async function?

Tags: asynchronous, rust

Consider following async function:

```
async fn call_me<F>(f : F ) -> Result<(), Error> 
where F : FnOnce() -> Result<(), Error> {
    f()
}
```

Is there any way to delay the execution **inside** `f()`?

- `std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(...)` will set the current thread to sleep,
- `tokio::time::delay_for(..)` can only be used in async contexts
- async closures are still [unstable](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/62290)

Comment: Can `f()` run on its own thread? Then you could easily use `std::thread::sleep` in that thread.

Comment: unfortunately not :( the function will eventually be executed by `tokio::time::timeout` to be halted after some `hard`deadline

Comment: If `f()` is a long-running synchronous function, `tokio::time::timeout` won't be able to stop it either. It would have to run in a different thread and the timeout would have to terminate the thread. Is `f()` a very CPU-bound task?

Comment: well, one solution would be to pass a future itself, instead of a closure. If that works, I will answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very similar to an async closure is a closure that returns a `Future` (which happens to be an async block)

```rust
async fn call_me<F, Fut>(f: F) -> Result<(), ()>
where
    F: FnOnce() -> Fut,
    Fut: Future<Output = Result<(), ()>>,
{
    f().await
}

#[tokio_macros::main]
async fn main() {
    call_me(|| async {
        tokio::time::delay_for(std::time::Duration::from_secs(10)).await;
        Ok(())
    })
    .await
    .unwrap();
}
```

Comment: that's elegant!

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is to pass an `std::future::Future` directly:

```
async fn call_me(f : Future) -> Result<(), Error) {
    tokio::time::timeout(tokio::time::Duration(1_000), f()).await
}

async fn some_async_function() -> Result<(), Error> {
   tokio::time::delay_for(tokio::time::Duration::from_millis(10_000).await;
   Ok(()
}

#[tokio:main]
async fn main() {
   call_me(some_async_function()).await;
}
```